# Possible stupid error! IF statement not running?

Tags: php, html, mysql

A little context, the registration part works fine, however I want to now add a login system. I want to test to see if the username exists but this isn't working.

Can anyone spot the error here?

Feel free to check it on a server over [here](http://valhq.com/login) - it's a WIP so there's still lots to do. **The username "Lewis" is currently entered into the database for testing purposes.**
As you can see, after the form has been filled etc. none of the echo statements run, in fact, even if an echo is put directly below the first 'IF' statement, it still doesn't print, so what is the problem? I've also tried changing the IF to:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
```

Still no luck.

PHP:

```
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

require 'vdb_includes/db.php';
require 'functions.php';


if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pw'])){

    $verifyUsername = $_POST['username'];
    $verifyPassword = $_POST['pw'];

    $usernameCheck = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$verifyUsername."'");
    if($usernameCheck->num_rows){
        echo "Username exists";
    } else {
        echo "Non existant";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="login_form" action="http://valhq.com/login" method="POST">
            <div class="login_form_content">
                <div class="login_form_input">
                    <input type="text" class="login_input_style" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" maxlength="20">
                </div>
                <div class="login_form_input">
                        <input type="password" class="login_input_style" placeholder="Password" id="pw" name="pw" maxlength="56">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="login_submit" value="Login">
                <div class="login_notMember">
                    <a href="http://valhq.com/register">Don't have an account? Sign up.</a>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: I'm aware, that's something I'll be fixing earlier by changing to prepared statements. However can you help with the question?

Comment: Also, would disabling whitespace and symbols with preg_match stop SQL injections?

Comment: Can you please try this as your query? `"SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='".$verifyUsername."'"`

Comment: No, use parameterized queries to prevent SQL injections. When I submit your form there is a 301 thrown, wheres that coming from?

Comment: As far as I know the only redirects setup are from the register page, which both redirect to either a success/fail page depending on the database insertion. On the login page, I've not setup any redirects other than the form action

Comment: Maybe you have a global re-write rule in place? Open developer console and watch the request when you submit.

Comment: Thanks for the input Irvin, unfortunately still no luck

Comment: I can't see anything in the console myself. The PHP shown above is the entire PHP used on the page. I used the same form ID/name for username and password, as I did in the register page; would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Nope, should be able to use the same names. Not the console, the network tab, and check `preserve log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 301 redirect to add a slash at the end of your url when it's missing. You haven't got a slash at the end of your form action and because of that the form post gets redirected to the url with the slash. Solution: add a slash at the end of the form action and it will work.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now!